# How can i print receipt use unity on receipt printer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I write an unity program for restaurants and cafes. I want to get a print button for the receipt printer and I do not know how to do it! How can I send the data and print it out. Thank you for helping me

edit1 : In fact, I did not find any information that would be useful !!!

Comment: This is heavily dependent on the printer. Some will have their own API's, some will use windows print api, there's really not much we can say without you specifying which printer you use

Comment: can you please share what research you have done for this till now

Comment: I do not have a receipt printer right now! And just have a common Canon printer just for testing print in unity !!